# Exported Activity Permission for AppWidget Configuration Activity

Tags: android, permissions, manifest, android-appwidget

I'm getting this warning for my AppWidget's configuration activity in the manifest file after I added the `android:exported="true"` tag. This is what it looks like...

```
<activity android:name=".widgets.WidgetConfigurationActivity"
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"
              android:exported="true" >
         <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_CONFIGURE" />
         </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

The warning I'm getting is "Exported activity does not require permission". From my understanding, setting the `exported` tag to true means that another application not related to my app can access it (which would make sense since the home screen launcher apps needs to launch my AppWidget's configuration activity). Does anyone know what kind of permission I need to add here to make this not give an error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> From my understanding, setting the exported tag to true means that another application not related to my app can access it

Correct. Note that it is superfluous here: having an `<intent-filter>` makes the activity be exported by default.

> Does anyone know what kind of permission I need to add here to make this not give an error?

AFAIK, you cannot guarantee that the home screen has any particular permission.

IMHO, this is an erroneous warning, one [that I filed a related issue for](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=33976) that should be fixed someday.

Comment: Alright, thanks a lot! I guess I'll just ignore this lint warning for now then.

Answer (score -1):

You can change the attribute `android:exported="true"` to `android:exported="false"`.

That should fix the problem for you.

Comment: If he sets android:exported="false" then the app's users won't be able to put the widget on the home screen, because the launcher won't have permission to launch the APPWIDGET_CONFIGURE intent.

Comment: @Omar & jenzz Please remove or update this answer, as it's wrong in 'this case'.