# android:Exported activity does not require permission

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator

When i add screens(src folder) info in manifest file i got this warning "Exported activity does not require permission" , but can't able to solve this problem.Can anybody provide solution for this.
Please suggest me how add screens(src folder) in Manifest file

```
<application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name="com.projectmine.Simpleproject">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        >
    </activity>
    <activity
         android:name="com.projectmine.MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.projectmine.MAINACTIVITY" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 4):

Please try this:

```
<application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
<activity android:name="com.projectmine.Simpleproject">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity
     android:name="com.projectmine.MainActivity">
</activity>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
android:exported="false"
```

to your Activity definition

**Edit:** you can have more information about android:exported on :  [Android Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html)

also as rIHaN JiTHiN 's answer it might occurred because of intent filters of your MainActivity

Comment: Yes tried that one also but app doesnt works and force closes

Answer (score 0):

This is an erroneous warning, that has been filed a related issue [here](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=33976) by [CommonsWare](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware) for that should be fixed someday.

For similar thread visit [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11916590/exported-activity-permission-for-appwidget-configuration-activity)